# get an array that does not exist in another array

Tags: php, arrays

for example I have 2 arrays like the following:

```
array1 = (2, 3, 4);
array2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

I want to get the value of the second array, where the value array1 is not found in array2, so we can conclude the following are array3

```
array3 = (1, 5);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diff the arrays

```
$array3 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array3 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Explosion Pills's answer is better. -1